# @font-face do CSS instala a fonte no computador ou só usa no site?

Tags: html5, css3

Me disseram que quando uso @font-face em uma página e alguém a acessa, o sistema operacional baixa e instala a fonte.

Acontece que eu notei o seguinte: ao criar um arquivo com @font-face e acessar, a fonte aparece corretamente, mas se em seguida eu removo o @font-face e abro a mesma página, a fonte não carrega, ou seja, não foi instalada no meu pc.

Concluí que a fonte só aparece no site, é correta esta afirmação?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
@font-face {
font-family: "scarface";
src: url("/wp-content/uploads/fonts/scarface-webfont.eot"); /* para IE */
src: local("scarface"), url("/wp-content/uploads/fonts/scarface-webfont.ttf") format("opentype");
}

body { font-family: "scarface", Cursive; font-size: 24px; }

</style>

</head>
<body>

   Texto

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não sou a favor de edições radicais, mas neste caso acho saudável. Caso não concorde, pode editar e até reverter. No entanto, procure analisar as minhas alterações e entender o porque delas.

Comment: Bacco ate eu entendi melhor com a sua edição, fico uma merda oque eu fiz, mas to a 17 horas no pc criando um site aqui ja to todo errado kk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### @font-face não instala a fonte no OS:

Sua afirmativa é correta, tanto que a diretiva @font-face baixa a fonte para uso no browser, e não tem relação nenhuma com as fontes do sistema operacional, tanto que os formatos mais comuns para web como .eot, .woff e .svg não são compatíveis com os do sistema (o ttf é exceção).

A fonte nunca é instalada no sistema (nem temporariamente), tanto que se você estiver com o browser aberto na página, mesmo com a fonte aparecendo corretamente, ela não vai estar disponível em outras aplicações.

Basta fazer o teste: abra uma página com fontes personalizadas, e em seguida rode um aplicativo como o Word, ou Photoshop, qualquer um que tenha escolha de fontes. Você vai notar que a fonte do site não aparece entre as disponíveis pelo OS (o que é bom, senão seu sistema viraria uma bagunça).

Comment: Foi isso que eu pensei também!

Comment: Então eu posso remover o local("scarface") porque ele não serve pra nada correto?

Comment: Nesse caso específico, o local só faria sentido se você quisesse, por exemplo usar uma fonte do sistema, mas chamar ela por outro nome no css, como font-family "Araruta" local('Arial'), ou priorizar a local caso já esteja instalada. Na prática mesmo normalmente não faz sentido, inclusive é arriscado ter outra de nome igual no OS, completamente diferente, e bagunçar seu layout. Eu evitaria o local() sim.

Comment: @LucasC.S inclusive, seria interessante você ver os formatos woff e svg, muitas vezes o woff é menor que o ttf, melhorando a performance da página (mas mantendo o .eot pro IE). Veja essa página com um exemplo bom de font-face: http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/ (e de brinde essa com uma técnica pra matar o local() : http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2010/05/20/bulletproof-smiley-font-face-syntax/ )

Answer (score 3):

O valor `local()` faz com que o browser procure a font no computador do visitante antes de executar o download da que está no servidor.

Mas pelos meus conhecimentos ele não baixa, se você pegar uma do google fonts por exemplo, ele apenas instala temporariamente (até que você retire do site) no site. Mais informações você encontra [aqui](http://tableless.com.br/font-face-fonts-externas-na-web/).

Comment: Então eu estou certo né?

Comment: Imagino que sim!!