# Como utilizar @Font-face com uma fonte arbitrária?

Tags: html5, css3

Gostaria de saber como funciona *@font-face* como devo aplica-lo no meu código *CSS* pois quero usar uma fonte que se chama *Tekton Pro* porém se somente utilizar a tag *font-family:Tekton Pro* não funciona e gostaria que ela pega-se nos navegadores: Google chrome,Mozila e Safari.

Obs afinal de contas oque devo fazer e baixar um arquivo com as fontes e colocar na pasta do projeto e setar no meu código ou apenas colocar a url das fontes direto no meu código( se sim qual seria o site ).

Comment: você pode encontrar a resposta dessa pergunta aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11072/font-face-do-css-instala-a-fonte-no-computador-ou-s%C3%B3-usa-no-site

Comment: então @ErlonCharles eu li la porem nao entendi uma coisa essa font face e uma url que coloco direto no meu codigo css ou e um arquivo que baixo coloco na minha pasta do projeto e seto ele no codigo

Comment: Você importa um arquivo defonte externa para o seu css, nomeia essa fonte importada e usa essa nova fonte externa como se fosse as fontes nativas.

Comment: so que ai eu nao usaria mais @font-face e sim import ???? poderia fazer uma simulação com essa fonte teken pro

Comment: `@font-face {
font-family: "Nome-da-Fonte";
src: url("caminho da fonte"); /* para IE */
src: local("nome-da-fonte"), url("caminho da fonte") format("opentype");
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer de dois jeitos:

#### 1 - Possuir a fonte localmente

Fazer o *download* da fonte, salvar no seu projeto e referenciar no CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("OpenSans.woff");
}
```

E utilizar o nome que está em `font-family` no resto do arquivo CSS.

Lembrando que existem fontes gratuitas e pagas. Um bom site é o [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/).

#### 2 - Utilizar o [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)

[Exemplo da Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans)

Você escolhe os estilos que você quer e ele te gera um *link*. Neste *link*, tem os `@font-face` definidos conforme você escolheu antes. A partir daí, basta colocar este *link* no `head` e usar a fonte normalmente.

Exemplo:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h1>Texto na fonte Open Sans</h1>
```

#### Sobre compatibilidade

Existem vários formatos de fonte: WOFF, WOFF2, TTF, SVG, EOT, OTF, e nem todos os navegadores suportam todos estes tipos. A melhor maneira de garantir compatibilidade com todos os navegadores, é possuir a fonte em todos estes formatos (você pode colocar vários `url()` no `@font-face`, um para cada arquivo).

Se você não liga pra IE8-, utilize WOFF, que possui [compatibilidade](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) com IE9+ e os principais navegadores, inclusive móveis.

Acredito que a melhor maneira ainda é deixar a responsabilidade com o Google Fonts, pois além de usar cache, normalmente ele garante a compatibilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Deve ser problema com path.

Fiz um exemplo usando "font online":

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfvLqdno/)

Veja se rola ai no seu código.

Comment: funcionou mais e normal isso ser deste tamnho e coreto utilizar dessa forma